# Insert & save with mongoose collection

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I am trying to insert new records into my MongoDB using Mongoose.  I have the following coffeescript, iterating over an array of ad_units:

```
campaign_doc = new mongoose.Collection 'scheduled_campaigns', db
for unit in ad_units
campaign = new campaign_model unit
campaign_doc.insert campaign
campaign.save()
```

The code runs and no errors are thrown.  However, my collection is not updated.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue: it was a connection problem.  The code in fact works, I just had to run it from a different server.